# Why Does Asynchronous UDP Datagram Haskell Server Have Packet Loss?

Tags: haskell

I am sending simple UDP packets to this Haskell server. For a source of packets I use a plain text file generated by "aspell -l en dump master". However, any list of over 120,000 messages should work. If I start the consumer and producer at the same time, I do not loose packets. However, I want to be able to simulate a very busy consumer. If I introduce a threadDelay for 20 seconds before starting the consumer, I get packet loss. This to me is counter intuitive because I am doing less with standard out and disk IO when I delay consuming. Can anyone explain why I am getting loss with the delayed version? How can I manage the socket and TChan work better to not get any loss (just higher memory usage) while my consumer is very busy?

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.STM (writeTChan, readTChan, atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan
import Network.Socket hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Data.ByteString hiding(putStrLn, head)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Char8 (putStrLn, putStr)
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $  do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    addrinfos <- getAddrInfo
                 (Just (defaultHints {addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE]}))
                 Nothing (Just "2000")
    let serveraddr = head addrinfos
    sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Datagram defaultProtocol
    bindSocket sock (addrAddress serveraddr)
    chan <- newTChanIO
    forkIO(producer chan sock)
    -- Uncomment the threadDelay below to see lossy version
    -- threadDelay (1000000 * 20)
    forkIO(consumer chan)
    forever $ threadDelay (1000000 * 60)

producer :: TChan ByteString -> Socket -> IO ()
producer chan sock = forever $ do
    (msg) <- recv sock 256
    atomically $ writeTChan chan msg

consumer :: TChan ByteString -> IO ()
consumer chan = forever $ do
    msg <- atomically $ readTChan chan
    Char8.putStr msg
```

Comment: For what it's worth, neither of these are lossless here. I reliably get exactly 30013 lines of output, whether the `threadDelay (1000000 * 20)` is there or not, even though `aspell -l en dump master` prints 119773 lines. To help others reproduce, here's the commands I run: `ghc -threaded -rtsopts -O2 test && ./test +RTS -N2 > test.out & sleep 1 && aspell -l en dump master | tee aspell.out | netcat -u localhost 2000`. You can kill both jobs when `test.out` and `aspell.out` stop changing (usually <1s).

Comment: I get all aspell lines if I compile unthreaded, `ghc server.hs` and run `./server > output`. If I compile -threaded, I always get loss. The threaded problem simply adds to my confusion about why I cannot work with this recv sock in a non blocking way. Thanks

Comment: It also seems highly dependent on the buffer size: if I change `recv sock 256` to `recv sock 1024` I get no loss, whether or not the consumer is delayed. (In fact, in all my experiments, I haven't found any circumstance under which the delayed consumer had a different behavior from the immediate consumer.)

Comment: I think netcat is faster than the actual client I was using which was just a simple Java program that read from the apsell.out file. Your suggestion of netcat is helpful. I see the same improvement with the buffer size. I will continue to test with larger messages which is my goal.

Comment: I'm suspicious of netcat (nc on Mac OS X in my case). While waiting for the threadDelay and the consumer to start, the memory usage of the server process does not go up. It should go up as the channel receives all the writes.

Comment: OK, netcat seems fine. apsell.out was too small to register higher memory usage. Larger files exhibit the expected memory growth.

Comment: I have used pipe view (`pv`) to rate limit the traffic and get it in line with my slower Java program. `cat large.log | pv -L 30m | nc -u 127.0.0.1 2000`. I still get loss even with a rate limit of 4m which makes me suspect netcat or at least pv again. If I compile unthreaded and send from a Java program I get no loss when producing and consuming. I get loss is I delay the consumer. In my actual message source, the messages are about 124 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not expect data loss?  This would happen in any language, not just Haskell, because the kernel has only a limited amount of buffer space for each socket.  Since, unlike TCP, UDP is not flow controlled, the kernel will just drop packets.  You can of course increase your buffer size with the SO_RCVBUF socket option.  But fundamentally UDP is not reliable anyway, so any real application using it needs to handle packet loss.